# Никчемный или никчёмный?

Tags: орфография

Встретился вчера в тексте вариант "никчёмный". Скажите, пожалуйста, допустимо так писать или это ошибка?
Спасибо

Comment: По моему мнению, русские должны писать "никчомный" вместо "никчёмный" и, тем более, "никчемный".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Варианты никчемный и никчёмный верны оба. Причём совсем недавно чаще употреблялся как раз никчёмный:

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%ED%E8%EA%F7%E5%EC%ED%FB%E9

Орфографический словарь
никчёмный; кр. ф. -мен, -мна

Большой толковый словарь НИКЧЁМНЫЙ -. Разг.
Ненужный, бесполезный. Тяготила н-ая работа.

Русское словесное ударение
никчёмный, -мен, -мна, -мно, -мны; сравн.ст. -ее [не никчемный]

У Ушакова:   http://www.slovopedia.com/3/205/805034.html 
 НИКЧЁМНЫЙ
и (реже) НИКЧЕМНЫЙ, никчёмная, никчёмное (разг.). Никуда не годный; излишний, бесполезный.

Об истории появления слова здесь:
http://wordhist.narod.ru/nikchemnij.html

Слова никчемный, никчемность в украинском и белорусском языках сложились и укрепились гораздо раньше, чем в русском. Оттуда пришли к нам, но и без них по законам русского словообразования при наличии выражения ни к чему появилось  самостоятельно произведенное русское разговорное прилагательное — никчёмный с его субстантивным дериватом — никчёмность. (Ср., например, в воронежск. гов. никчамушный, никуда не годный, не нужный).

Так что никчёмный воспринимается как русское разговорное слово, никчемный - как заимствование.

Answer (score 2):

при выполнении тестов по русскому языку, следует выбрать слово никчёмный

Answer (score 1):

1. На примере "никчемный - никчёмный" интересно понаблюдать за парными фонетическими вариантами. Вот «М. Горький выдумывает или заимствует из малороссийского  языка слово НИКЧЕМНЫЙ", а вот словарь Резниченко  через сто лет (2009 год) объявляет это слово устаревшим (даже не разговорным). Влияют ли филологи-лингвисты на судьбу слова? Очевидно, да, если они выбирают понравившееся им  слово и назначают его главным. Наверное, СЛЕДУЕТ как-то регулировать языковые процессы, но делать это надо очень ТЩАТЕЛЬНО, проводя анализ всех факторов.
2. Вот попробуем  провести такой анализ для пары "никчемный - никчёмный". Здесь может сказываться влияние двух моментов:

1) Для русского языка характерно историческое чередование Е/Ё при смене безударной и ударной позиции: ни к чему→ никчёмный. Тогда больше подходит этот  вариант. 
  2) С другой стороны, следует учесть, что небольшом количестве случаев буква Ё (и обозначаемый ею звук) приобретают самостоятельность и становятся независимыми, например: ВСЕ – ВСЁ, ЧЕМ (Т.п.) – В ЧЁМ  (П.п.). Тогда форма НИКЧЕМНЫЙ также подходит.

1. Понаблюдать за естественным поведением слова и собрать статистику  за такой короткий промежуток времени сложно, да и необозначенная буква Ё не позволит этого сделать, - так что проблемы его правильного произношения  на ближайшее время гарантированы.